# ¿Por qué separar PHP de HTML entre las comillas de un ECHO?

Tags: php, html5

```
$color = "rojo";
echo "Mi auto es " . $color . "<br>";
echo "Mi auto es $color. <br>";
```

Mi pregunta es ¿por qué no usar simplemente la segunda opción? La primera opción la encontré en W3C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta concreta a tu pregunta es que la opción:

```
echo "Mi auto es " . $color . "<br>";
```

es más legible que:

```
echo "Mi auto es $color<br>";
```

#### Lo que podemos hacer

PHP es muy flexible, o permisivo... Entonces, 
***hay varias formas de "manejar" cadenas en PHP***, en cuanto a las comillas, su unión, etc. Usar una u otra afecta tanto a la legibilidad como al rendimiento. Por ejemplo, funcionará:

```
# Usar comillas dobles
$color = "rojo";
echo "Mi auto es " . $color . "<br>";
echo "Mi auto es $color<br>";
echo "Mi auto es {$color}<br>";

# Usar comillas simples
$color = 'rojo';
echo 'Mi auto es ' . $color . '<br>';

# Combinar comillas (esto es mas feo que pegarle a una madre)
echo 'Mi auto es ' . $color . "<br>";
echo 'Mi auto es ' . "$color<br>";
echo 'Mi auto es ' . "{$color}<br>";

# Y siguiendo con los ejemplos anteriores
# Almacenar en variables
$str = "Mi auto es $color<br>";
$str = "Mi auto es {$color}<br>";
$str = "Mi auto es " . $color . "<br>";
$str = 'Mi auto es ' . $color . '<br>';

echo $str; // imprimo la última asignación
```

#### Lo que deberíamos hacer

Según la situación, puedes elegir:

- ***Legibilidad y rendimiento***, comillas simples para declarar el valor de la variable, y para imprimir comillas simples y concatenamos:

  $color = 'rojo';
  echo 'Mi auto es ' . $color . '
  ';
- ***Rendimiento***, comillas simples para declarar el valor de la variable, comillas dobles y la variable entre corchetes al imprimir:

  $color = 'rojo';
  echo "Mi auto es {$color} 
  ";

#### Consideraciones

***El rendimiento depende de cómo trata el intérprete de PHP las cadenas.***

Al usar comillas simples el intérprete "entiende" que sólo hay un string, no busca variables en su interior, es por eso que:

```
echo 'Mi auto es $color <br>';   // imprime: Mi auto es $color <br>
echo 'Mi auto es {$color} <br>'; // imprime: Mi auto es {$color} <br>
```

Al usar comillas dobles el intérprete "entiende" que puede haber variables dentro del string, aunque no las haya, esto hace su tratamiento más trabajoso. Aquí, cuando ponemos las variables entre llaves:

```
echo "Mi auto es {$color} <br>";
```

aunque se tenga que interpretar el string, ya le indicamos donde hay una variable, lo que hace el tratamiento más rápido que en el caso de no indicarlo.

Answer (score 2):

**USO DE COMILLAS DOBLES**

Con el uso de las comillas dobles, meter una variable dentro de ellas, hace que se interprete el contenido de ellas

De hecho también sería válido y correcto que tu código quedara del modo siguiente

```
<?php

$color = "rojo";
echo "Mi auto es {$color}.<br>";
```

**USO DE COMILLAS SIMPLES**

´Por el contrario si declaras tu código del modo siguiente

```
<?php

$color = "rojo";
echo 'Mi auto es $color.<br />';
```

La etiqueta html `<br>` será interpretada correctamente pero la variable `$color` se leerá de forma literal como otro fragmento de código, pues las comillas simples no harán interpretación y menos interpolación del valor que tiene asignada la variable

**ACLARACIONES**

Ahora con respecto al primer ejemplo, se debería de aplicar en escenarios como el siguiente ejemplo

```
<?php

$color = "rojo";
echo 'Mi auto es'.$color.'<br />';
```

**¿Por qué?**

Bueno por que las comillas simples leerán solo texto y al hacer el proceso de concatenación `.$variable.` logramos que ese valor sea interpretado

De hecho el ejemplo anterior funciona perfecto con el uso de comillas dobles como vez en el siguiente script:

```
<?php

$color = "rojo";
echo "Mi auto es".$color."<br />";
```

**¿Pero entonces cual usar?**

1. Si tu función de impresión no maneja valores dinámicos dentro de ella, entonces usar comillas simples `''`
2. Si tu función requiere interpolar con valores dinámicos que provienen por ejemplo de variables entonces mejor usa comillas dobles `""`

Comment: Yo añadiría: mejor usa comillas dobles para todo, y te quitas de problemas.